# Detecting rotation angle of text in an image

Tags: python, opencv

So, i have an image with a text that is not in position to allow me to extract informations from it, so i need to find somehow to rotate it.

I have tried so many libraries and theories but nothing works especially
OpenCV.
i'll join an image exemple that needs to be rotated.
thanks a lot.

"https://drive.google.com/open?id=1gzF1VLtb8Q7gOQ6u0IzrB98Ae1VC3TPF"

i tried this for example :

```
import numpy as np
import cv2

image = cv2.imread("test1.jpg")
gray = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
gray = cv2.bitwise_not(gray)

thresh = cv2.threshold(gray, 0, 255,cv2.THRESH_BINARY | cv2.THRESH_OTSU)[1]

coords = np.column_stack(np.where(thresh > 0))
print coords
angle = cv2.minAreaRect(coords)[-1]
print angle 
if angle < -45:
    angle = -(90 + angle)
else:
    angle = -angle

(h, w) = image.shape[:2]
center = (w // 2, h // 2)
M = cv2.getRotationMatrix2D(center, angle, 1.0)
rotated = cv2.warpAffine(image, M, (w, h),flags=cv2.INTER_CUBIC, borderMode=cv2.BORDER_REPLICATE)   


cv2.putText(rotated, "Angle: {:.2f} degrees".format(angle),(10, 30), cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, 0.7, (0, 0, 255), 2)

print("[INFO] angle: {:.3f}".format(angle))
```

I tried also this theorie :
Scan a document at a specific orientation and sum up the number of "black" pixels on each scan line (creating a 1D array of counts, each index representing a Y coordinate, the profile).
Calculate the variance of the counts (profile).
Repeat for multiple angles, (can be done in a binary search fashion to reduce processing)
The angle that results in the greatest variance is the correct angle (due to the text lines creating large peaks from the printed text, and low valleys due to the absence of text between the lines)
Then after finding this angle you can adjust your image accordingly and do your awesome OCR.
The code below :

```
from PIL import Image

from resizeimage import resizeimage

jpgfile = Image.open("test.jpg")

#size = jpgfile.size[0]/5 , jpgfile.size[1]/5

#cover = resizeimage.resize_cover(jpgfile, size)

#cover.show()

for i in range(0,360):
#a reviser
    rotated = jpgfile.rotate(i)
    rotated.save("out.jpg")
    image = cv2.imread("out.jpg")
    gray = cv2.cvtColor(image,cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    ret,thresh = cv2.threshold(gray,127,255,cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV)
#cv2.imshow('binary',thresh)
#cv2.waitKey(0)

    thresh_sum = thresh.sum(axis=1)
#thresh_sum.show

    a = []

    a = np.append(a,thresh_sum)
    variance = 0
    variance = np.var(thresh_sum,0)

    print(variance,i)

rotated.show()
```

Comment: What have you tried and it didn't work?

Comment: Write what you tried and then I may write solution for you

Comment: If you are willing to use ImageMagick on a Unix-like environment, I have a textdeskew script that will do that at my web site at http://www.fmwconcepts.com/imagemagick/index.php. It uses FFT processing to find the orientation of the lines of text.